# How display only div with selected tag with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, filter, tags

I created a working multiple tag filter with four `<input type="checkbox">` which each have a tag which are also in my `div` class (code below) but I have an issue when two checkboxes are selected.

None of my `div` contains all four `id` in their class name but they all appear on my screen when I select all checkboxes while none should appear.

*Here is an example to illustrate my point :*

---

```
<div class="filterDiv adobePhotoshop sketch"> Div1 </div>
<div class="filterDiv adobePhotoshop adobeIndesign"> Div2 </div>
```

When I check my "Adobe Photoshop" and "Sketch" checkboxes for instance, I have div1 and div2 appearing while I only want to make appear div1 (because div2 have adobePhotoshop too but NOT sketch).

---

Any idea of how can I manage this please?

**Javascript** :

```
const filterToggle = (e) => {
    const checkedFilters = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')].map(
        (el) => el.id
      ),
      toFilter = [...document.querySelectorAll('.filterDiv')];

    if (checkedFilters.length === 0) {
      toFilter.forEach(
        (el) => el.style.display = 'flex'
      )
    } else {
      toFilter.forEach(
        (el) => el.style.display = 'none'
      );

      let selector = checkedFilters.map(
        (f) => `.filterDiv.${f}`
      ).join(',');
      document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(
        (el) => el.style.display = 'flex'
      );
    };
};

filters = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

filters.forEach(
  (f) => f.addEventListener('change', filterToggle)
);
```

**HTML** :

```
<div id="btn-container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="adobePhotoshop"> <label for="adobePhotoshop">Adobe Photoshop</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="adobeIndesign"> <label for="adobeIndesign">Adobe Indesign</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="adobeIllustrator"> <label for="adobeIllustrator">Adobe Illustrator</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sketch"> <label for="sketch">Sketch</label>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="filterDiv adobePhotoshop adobeIndesign adobeIllustrator">
    Project1
    </div>
    <div class="filterDiv adobeIndesign adobeIllustrator">
    Project2
    </div>
    <div class="filterDiv adobePhotoshop">
    Project3
    </div>
    <div class="filterDiv adobePhotoshop sketch">
    Project4
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 60px;
}

.filterDiv {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I think you should change the `let selector` value into:  `.filterDiv.${checkedFilters.join('.')}`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed my problem :) ! Can you add this comment into an answer so I can mark it as the right answer please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let selector = checkedFilters.map(
  (f) => `.filterDiv.${f}`
).join(',');
```

Let's assume the "adobePhotoshop" and "sketch" were checked. The code above should generate an array of class names selector:

```
[".filterDiv.adobePhotoshop", ".filterDiv.sketch"]
```

... which is used to select elements using:

```
document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(
  (el) => el.style.display = 'flex'
);
```

... which is mimicking the **OR** condition, where it will select elements that have at least one of them (`".filterDiv.adobePhotoshop"` or `".filterDiv.sketch"`) in the class names.

In order to make the filtering to be the **AND** condition, then the selector logic should be:

```
let selector = `.filterDiv.${checkedFilters.join('.')}`;
```

... to generate class name selector that only select elements that have all of the conditions:

```
.filterDiv.adobePohotoshop.sketch
```